# Laravel Elquent has-many -deep

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have spent better part of the weekend tyring to solve this problem. This is what I want to achieve. I have Four tables. Country | User | Post | Comment.
This is the structure of these tables.

Country Table
country_id (PrimaryKey)
country_name

User Table
user_id (PrimaryKey)
country_id (ForeignKey)
user_name

Post Table
post_id (PrimaryKey)
user_id (ForeignKey)
comment_id (ForeignKey)
post_name

Comment Table
comment_id (PrimaryKey)
comment_name

Now. I have already created relationship between CountryTable->UserTable, CountryTable->Usertable->PostTable using has-many-through approach. Now I want to know how to create Has-Many-Deep relationship between Country Table and Comment Table. Guys I appreciate you help in advise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `Country Table` and `User Table` structure was good enough. However, your Post Table should be `post_id (PrimaryKey) user_id (ForeignKey) post_name` because one post has multiple comments so can't store `comment_id` to `Post table`

Secondly, your Comment table structure has some missing information should be `comment_id(PrimaryKey), post_id(ForeignKey), user_id(ForeignKey), comment`

Thirdly, you can't relation between Country table and Comment table until store country_id to the comment table so there is a silly solution but I can't personally prefer because already `user_id` on `Comment table`

**So now you can fetch comments like this way:**

```
 public function getCommentsByCountry(Country $country)
 {
     return Comment::whereHas('users', function($users){
         $users->where('country_id', $country->id);
     })->get();
 }
```

Comment: Using Laravel eloquent relationship and polymorphic relationship is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this laravel package can help you [eloquent-has-many-deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

Example

```
class Country extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep('App\Comment', ['App\User', 'App\Post']);
    }
}
```